# How can I change the path to Java in Sublime?

Tags: java, build

I am using an office laptop and I do not have administrative rights to it therefore I cannot edit the environment variables.

Recently, my laptop auto updated to Java 8 but something got goofed up and when ever I try to build a java program I get an error. In the meantime, I would like to build and run Java programs on Sublime text using my functioning Java 7.

How can I change the path in Sublime Text to Java 7 instead of it defaulting to Java 8 when I press CTRL-B?

Comment: It might be time to use an IDE rather than a text editor. I know you can control this there.

Comment: Change it from terminal/command prompt ... but you will have to do this every time !

Comment: @Peter For full blown enterprise projects, I do use Eclipse, but thought of using Sublime for testing small java programs.

Comment: @rhel.user I use intellij even for one class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey me to ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make a special build system `JavaC7` or something like that:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/absolute/path/to/javac \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use java in sublime:
In sublime go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System
put below code:

```
 { 
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name", "&&", "java" ,"$file_base_name"], 
    "selector": "source.java",
     "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "path" : 
    "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2\\bin\\", 
     "shell":true
     }
```

Save it with any name (like, Runjava.sublime-build)

Note: In path give whatever java version present in your system at these location "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\"

Then, create a folder with three files in it B.java(Main java file), input.txt, output.txt.
Go to Tools -> Build System -> Select Runjava

put below code in B.java file:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            System.setIn(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));

            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Error");

        }
        
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }
}
```

give input in input.txt file

see output in ouput.txt file